# Will a NodeJs app automatically restart upon crash when using nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm learning, bit by bit, nginx in conjunction with a NodeJs app on linux.
I'm wondering if nginx is taking care of automatically restarting the nodeJs app in the event of a crash?
thx

Comment: Whatever is starting your node application is also responsible for restarting it. Nginx shouldn't need to know anything about node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nginx won't restart node.js. You need to use something like [`forever`](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to make sure that node.js restarts itself if it dies.